# while(sqlite3_step(ReturnStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)

Tags: ios, sqlite

I want to get records for specific city but While statement not working when i debug this code, it always goes outside loop.

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getAddressCellLatLong :(NSString *)clinicCity
    {
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString * sqlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select address,phone,mobile,type,latitude,longitude from getclinic where city ='%@'",clinicCity];
        sqlite3_stmt *ReturnStatement = (sqlite3_stmt *) [self getStatement: sqlStr];
        while(sqlite3_step(ReturnStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            @try
            {
                ClinicDC* clinic = [[ClinicDC alloc]init];
                NSString *clinicID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 0)];
                 NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 1)];
                 NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 2)];
                 NSString *mobile = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 3)];
                 NSString *type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 4)];
                 NSString *city = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 5)];
                 NSString *country = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 6)];
                 NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 7)];
                 NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement, 8)];
                clinic.clinicID = [clinicID intValue];
                clinic.cCity = city;
                clinic.cCountry = country;
                clinic.cType = type;
                clinic.cAddress = address;
                clinic.cPhone = phone;
                clinic.cMobile = mobile;
                clinic.cLongitude = longitude;
                clinic.cLatitude = latitude;
                [dataArray addObject:clinic];

            }
            @catch (NSException *ept) {
                NSLog(@"Exception in %s, Reason: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [ept reason]);
            }

        }
        return dataArray;

    }
```

Comment: Is sqlite3_stmt *ReturnStatement = (sqlite3_stmt *) [self getStatement: sqlStr]; returning something valid or null?

Comment: yes every thing is fine.. i guess city is not primary key.. may b error can be due to this

Comment: To check the query I always download the db from xcode and open it in SqliteBrowser and run the query....

Comment: if you give the query as select * from getclinic, does your loop work?

Comment: no it does not work but i have checked query it is fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61020/discussion-between-debanjan-and-n-a).

Comment: Show `getStatement`.